# Is there a way to program a color-changing border that looks like an RGB light strip?

Tags: javascript, html, css, border, rgb

I'm currently getting ready to help a family member develop a website for their business. For the gaming portion of the website, I want to have a border at the bottom of the header that does a gradual RGB color change, almost like an RGB strip you mount on your wall would. I'm still pretty green to programming and development, so are there any ways to implement this natively or with a package? I know it'll probably require JavaScript, but is there a way to do this natively with CSS? Thanks!

Example of inspiration: https://youtu.be/Pxt9sGTsvFk?t=184

Comment: This might help you get started: https://codepen.io/bramus/pen/rNWByYz

Answer (score 0):

hello if you want to making moving or changing rbg border color you can use the code below i hope you find this answer helpful

HTML

```
<div class="block moving-glow"></div>
```

CSS

```
.block {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #000, #272727);
}

.moving-glow:before, .moving-glow:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    top: -2px;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fb0094, #0000ff, #00ff00,#ffff00, #ff0000, #fb0094, 
        #0000ff, #00ff00,#ffff00, #ff0000);
    background-size: 400%;
    width: calc(100% + 10px);
    height: calc(100% + 10px);
    z-index: -1;
    animation: anim-moving-glow 20s linear infinite;
  
}

@keyframes anim-moving-glow {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 400% 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
}

.moving-glow:after {
    filter: blur(30px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone has sent me exactly what I needed! Thanks LSE!

https://codepen.io/bramus/pen/rNWByYz

HTML:

```
<footer>
    <p>Demo 4/4 for <a href="https://brm.us/animated-gradient-border" target="_top">https://brm.us/animated-gradient-border</a></p>
    <p>Don't see an animation? That's because your browser does not support <code>@property</code>.<br />Check out <a href="https://codepen.io/bramus/pen/XWMwPgO" target="_top">this forked version</a> which includes a fallback for your browser.</p>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    --angle: 0deg;
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 50vmin;
    border: 10vmin solid;
    border-image: conic-gradient(from var(--angle), red, yellow, lime, aqua, blue, magenta, red) 1;

    animation: 10s rotate linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    to {
        --angle: 360deg;
    }
}

@property --angle {
  syntax: '<angle>';
  initial-value: 0deg;
  inherits: false;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: fixed;
    top: 1em;
    left: 1em;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:after {
    content: 'Toggle Fill';
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + div {
    border-image-slice: 1 fill;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    background: #fff;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can create rgb changing color border to the side border of the html page.

HTML Code: -

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="progressbar"></div>
        <div id="progressbar1"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS Code: -

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
body{
    background-color:black;
}
#progressbar
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff,#00ffe7);
    animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate
{
    0%,100%
    {
        filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%
    {
        filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
}

#progressbar:before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff,#00ffe7);
    filter: blur(30px);
}

#progressbar:after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff,#00ffe7);
    filter: blur(30px);
}

#progressbar1
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff,#00ffe7);
    animation: animate 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate
{
    0%,100%
    {
        filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%
    {
        filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
}

#progressbar1:before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff,#00ffe7);
    filter: blur(30px);
}

#progressbar1:after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #008aff,#00ffe7);
    filter: blur(30px);
}
```